# WSO2 AM - Calling web service for enrichment from an out sequence

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

This is what I try to solve:

1. Proxy in-sequence receives a request message and passes it to backend service
2. Proxy out-sequence receives the response message and iterates over each returned item
3. Call another service for each item and enrich the original message with some parts of the result from the second service
4. Return the enriched result from proxy to caller

What will be the proper mediators to use in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case of service chaining, where you can use the mediators iterate and aggregate

In this link, you can find a similar case.

http://dakshithar.blogspot.com/2012/07/routing-and-service-chaining-with-wso2_23.html

Comment: Would this way make it possible to store values from the first response message in the chain and use in the last aggregating one?

Comment: Yes, to my comment above.